# How do I set a part back to its original position and orientation? (Lua/Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

Is there an easier way to set the part to its original position instead of having to copy and paste its new location? I have falling blocks for my parkour but I want them to reset back to its original position and orientation after 3 seconds?

Comment: Nope, copying the original CFrame is the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to save the part's original CFrame on server start, or whenever the part's creation occurs.

```lua
local Part: Part = nil -- Change nil to the part.
local CoordinateFrame: CFrame = Part.CFrame

--[[
At this point, you'd write all of your code here.
Once finished, the script will then continue to return the part to it's previous CFrame which is stored into a variable (CoordinateFrame).
]]

Part.CFrame = CoordinateFrame
```